# How to handle a lot of media files in the uploads folder? (+10.000)

Tags: images, uploads, media-library, ftp, filesystem

I recently found out that FileZilla only displays 9998 files in a single folder, but our WordPress Media archive has over 58.000 pictures in three folders. So the standard sorting option by date (years and months) doesn't seem to be such a good fit for such a high amount of files. Is there any way to better sort these pictures into subfolders to make them manageable?

I already purchased the Enhanced Media Library plugin and the WordPress Media Library Folders plugin because it allows to actually move the pictures into subfolders, but with such a high number of file the interface doesn't even load. Same with the cPanel File Manager, takes forever to load and then crashes...
Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you SSH onto the server?

Comment: I had the same problem, and in fact, the default setting for years and months helps with this situation as the number of pictures will be spread over many folders.

With that amount of images there are perhaps thumbnails from old theme version or other unused image sizes - to clean up the media library there are only a few plugins out there https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-cleaner/ Media Cleaner is one of them. 

Use that plugin to clean up unused images.

Comment: Yes, I can SSH onto the server